# Archeological finds related to King Hezekiah's closing a wellspring under Jerusalem?

Tags: history, eretz-yisrael, geography, water, yerushalayim-jerusalem

The Gemara says that King Hezekiah (Chizkiyahu) closed one of the springs of water in (under?) Jerusalem, so the Assyrian army wouldn't be able to use it.

Do we have any guesses what exactly that waterway was, or how he closed it? I know there's recently been all sorts of explorations of the tunnels and waterways under Jerusalem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hezekiah%27s_Tunnel

Comment: +1 I also heard that Yosef buried tons and tons of gold underground in different places in the world. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: Shalom, can you cite where in the _g'mara_ this is, please?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I guess that Wikipedia article is basically the answer, no?

Comment: If you say so. Also,@HachamGabriel, that sounds like a good question to [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @HachamGabriel One of those places must have been San Francisco California :)

Answer (score 4):

The only natural fresh water source around Jerusalem is the Gihon spring located just to the east of the city. Originally, there was an aqueduct that brought water into the city, but it was at ground level and could relatively easily be attacked by opposing armies, as the spring was located outside the city walls due to engineering concerns. King Hezekiah in anticipation of the Assyrian armies' arrival dug an underground tunnel/aqueduct that went straight into the city. This tunnel, known now as Hezekiah's Tunnel, was rediscovered in 1838 and has since been open to the public to walk through. For more details see [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hezekiah%27s_Tunnel&ei=b48lT_PXB7G60QGM5_z5CA&usg=AFQjCNEK4Vpbu1TyP-rGCNy9Ja4KxRL5_g&sig2=FIJFtKpV8YDhgGRlf2_sOA) as well as numerous photos and information available through Google.

Sources: I've walked through it!